# ANTD List Component integration

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, antd

I want to implement list component load more button for my gatsby project, where I am using Gatsby Netlify CMS Starter template.

I have created a sandbox for this template and then installed "ANTD" plugin but it's not working. Can anyone guide how should I incorporate this and whats this error about?

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-cherry-fthf1?file=/src/components/LoadBlog.js

The same code works here: https://codesandbox.io/s/hbr8i?file=/index.js but not inside the Gatsby starter template, why is this so?

Comment: You're not exporting anything from your component.

Comment: How should I do that

Comment: You need to update your gatsby-config file. According to the documentation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gatsby-plugin-antd

Comment: Updated my config file https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-cherry-fthf1?file=/gatsby-config.js but getting this message error Command failed with exit code 137.

Comment: ERROR #10226  CONFIG

Couldn't find the "gatsby-plugin-antd" plugin declared in "/sandbox/gatsby-config.js".